# Stopping (orphaned?) Minecraft server properly

Tags: raspbian, server, windows, minecraft

I have a minecraft server running on my pi. I access the pi through putty on Windows. Is there any way to properly stop the server so that it saves, without having to keep the putty window open (and thus my computer on)?

I have tried `kill -2`, `-3`, and `-15` but 2 and 3 don't work. 15 breaks the server.

Comment: Thinking out of the box here: can't you just run it in a screen session and detach screen when you want to turn your Windows off, so the program will keep running and not turn it off? Check the [screen manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Invoking-Screen) on how to detach/retach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thinking outside of the box here:

Can't you just run it in a screen session and detach screen when you want to turn your Windows off, so the program will keep running and not turn it off?

Check the [screen manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Invoking-Screen) on how to detach/retach.

Screen is one of the most used utilities when you have a remote machine.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the minecraft server runs with java and `killall java` doesn't stop it.

I would take a look how the guys at Minecraft Server Manager do it ([http://msmhq.com](http://msmhq.com/)). It's open source.

Comment: i see what you are getting at, but I would prefer a solution that doesnt involve extra programs/downloads.

Comment: I should have said I sort of want to keep a vanilla server, as it were, not no downloads